# Sequence of letters of length $5$

Tags: probability

How many sequences of letters are there of length $5$ with exactly $2$ vowels? Don't count "y" as a vowel.

Pretty lost on this one. I know it involves a $\binom{5}{2}$ part, but I feel like that's not all.

Comment: Must the letters be distinct?  Or can letters be repeated?

Comment: they can be repeated @ScottH.

Answer (score 1):

You can select the positions of the two vowels in $\binom{5}{2}$ ways, and the vowels themselves in $5^2$ ways; the other 3 letters can be taken in $(26 - 5)^3$ ways.